# Python 3 Problems in VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Whenever I try to use pip3 on my MacOS in VS Code the terminal gives me the error below. The version of python 3 I have is 3.9.6, so I'm not sure why pip3 is trying to reference python 3.6. I'm not sure how to fix or change this. In the terminal on my Mac pip3 works fine it only has problems in the VS Code terminal.

```
python3.6: posix_spawn: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: Undefined error: 0
```

Comment: Have you used `Ctrl+Shift+P` and selected the appropriate python interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in VS code Terminal

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sudo pip install --upgrade pip` command.

Once the upgrade has finished, run this command: `pip --version` to check if you are on the latest version.

The Version should start with the number `21`

Happy coding (and welcome to the community!)